# HierarchyRequestError when appendChild(this.context1.canvas1)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a progress bar for a game I am working on.  But I get this HierarchyRequestError when I try to connect the canvas to a div.  Here is the code snippet. Any help would be appreciated.

```
this.setSizePercent(horizontalSizePercent, verticalSizePercent);
this.createCanvas();
this.createDOMElement();

return this;
```

};

//Prototype

COREHTML5.RoundedRectangle.prototype = {

```
createCanvas: function () {
    var canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
    this.context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
    return canvas1;
},
createDOMElement: function () {
    this.domElement = document.createElement('div');
    this.domElement.appendChild(this.context1.canvas1);
},
appendTo: function (element) {
    element.appendChild(this.domElement);
    this.domElement.style.width = element.offsetWidth + 'px';
    this.domElement.style.height = element.offsetHeight + 'px';
    this.resize(element.offsetWidth, element.offsetHeight);
},

resize: function (width, height) {
    this.HORIZONTAL_MARGIN = (width - width *
        this.horizontalSizePercent) / 2;
    this.VERTICAL_MARGIN = (height - height *
        this.verticalSizePercent) / 2;
    this.cornerRadius = (this.context1.canvas1.height / 2 -
        2 * this.VERTICAL_MARGIN) / 2;
    this.top = this.VERTICAL_MARGIN;
    this.left = this.HORIZONTAL_MARGIN;
    this.right = this.left + width - 2 * this.HORIZONTAL_MARGIN;
    this.bottom = this.top + height - 2 * this.VERTICAL_MARGIN;
```

Answer (score 0):

The property of 2D canvas contexts which retrieves the canvas element is called [`canvas`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-canvas).

Therefore, you should use

```
this.context1.canvas
```

instead of

```
this.context1.canvas1
```